# get UTC time directly from a website in python

Tags: python, utc

i want to get the utc time directly from a website that can give that. and i don't want to use python modules because they give me the system time and my system time does not show the correct time.
how can i get the correct utc time without changing the system time?
i use

```
import ntplib,datetime
x = ntplib.NTPClient()
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.request('europe.pool.ntp.org').tx_time)
```

but i get this error

```
raise NTPException("No response received from %s." % host)
ntplib.NTPException: No response received from europe.pool.ntp.org.
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy? it works for me.

Comment: @Sufiyan Ghori yes. is there another website that i can replace in this code?or any other way for this question?

Comment: FWIW, this should really be fixed by installing an NTP client as a constant background service on the machine to keep the actual machine time accurate, if at all possible.

Comment: From the response looks like site is not reachable from your computer. I tried the same code from my local desktop and it worked fine.

Comment: I had the same issue and it looked to be an intermittent network issue on a VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to call `datetime.utcnow()`? From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow)

Here is my output

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 4, 9, 47, 59, 572104)
```

**Edit as OP having issues with above**

As for a web based solution, this works fine for me (Whilst avoiding your website

```
>>> import requests
>>> x = requests.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London.txt')
>>> print(x.content)
b'abbreviation: GMT\ndatetime: 2018-11-04T10:09:18.395273+00:00\nday_of_week: 0\nday_of_year: 308\ndst: false\ndst_from: \ndst_until: \ntimezone: Europe/London\nunixtime: 1541326158\nutc_offset: +00:00\nweek_number: 44'
```

**Update**

You can get the datetime like so. I am certain there is a better way to do this, but this method works fine for this specific use-case.

```
>>> import requests
>>> x = requests.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London.txt')
>>> y = x.text
>>> print(y[27:47])
2018-11-04T11:01:46
```

Comment: i try that and it gives me the system time which i use. and my system doesn't show the correct time.i want to receive correct time although my system doesn't set on the correct time.

Comment: It should give you utc time. I will update my answer with a web-based solution also.

Comment: thank you it works. could you tell me how can i separate the unix time and put it in a separate variable?

Comment: Updated for you.